# Aspose pdf table

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose-cells, aspose.pdf

i have added a table with two rows and two columns and set border to all cells. but it shows the border only for first column

Sample code is shown below

> var tableestdet = new Table
>                   {
>                       ColumnWidths = "120,120",
>                       Margin = new MarginInfo { Top = 40, Left = 10 },
>
> ```
>                DefaultCellBorder = new BorderInfo((int)BorderSide.All, 1F),
>             };
>             tableestdet.DefaultCellTextInfo = new TextInfo { Alignment = AlignmentType.Center };
>             var estdet1 = tableestdet.Rows.Add();
>             estdet1.DefaultRowCellPadding = new MarginInfo { Top = 5, Bottom = 5 };
>             var req=estdet1.Cells.Add("Requested By:");
>            var estde=estdet1.Cells.Add("Entered By:");
>             var estdet2 = tableestdet.Rows.Add();               
>             estdet2.DefaultCellTextInfo = new TextInfo
>             {                 
>                 FontSize = 8,
>                 Alignment = AlignmentType.Center
>             };
>             estdet2.DefaultRowCellPadding = new MarginInfo { Top = 5, Bottom = 5 };
>             estdet2.Cells.Add(Requestedby);
>            estdet2.Cells.Add(CustomerName);
>            sec1.Paragraphs.Add(tableestdet);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We have noticed that you are working with an outdated version of the API so please upgrade to Aspose.PDF for .NET 19.2 which is latest available version of the API as it includes more features and bug fixes. You may use below code snippet to add a table on page of PDF document, while setting borders for all cells.

```
// Load source PDF document
Aspose.Pdf.Document document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document();
// Add a page to the document
Page page = document.Pages.Add();
// Initializes a new instance of the Table
Aspose.Pdf.Table table = new Aspose.Pdf.Table();
// Set the table border color as LightGray
table.Border = new Aspose.Pdf.BorderInfo(Aspose.Pdf.BorderSide.All, .5f, Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray));
// Set the border for table cells
table.DefaultCellBorder = new Aspose.Pdf.BorderInfo(Aspose.Pdf.BorderSide.All, .5f, Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray));
// Create a loop to add 10 rows
for (int row_count = 1; row_count <= 10; row_count++)
{
    // Add row to table
    Aspose.Pdf.Row row = table.Rows.Add();
    // Add table cells
    row.Cells.Add("Column (" + row_count + ", 1)");
    row.Cells.Add("Column (" + row_count + ", 2)");
}
// Add table object to first page of input document
page.Paragraphs.Add(table);
// Save updated document containing table object
document.Save(dataDir + "Table_19.2.pdf");
```

Generated PDF document has been attached for your kind reference [Table19.2.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mJQQdzNo_zKADXc4gEr0xyXpKmXDs_CJ/view?usp=sharing). Please feel free to let us know if you need any further assistance.

**PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.